# angular design material md-list-item in the right

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

According the example: https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.list

The checkboxes are alligned right: 
[image: Example Image]

What happens in my code is that the checkboxes appear under the text: 
[image: My result Image]

I don't know why the results are different because I copy pasted the example and I just changed `ng-repeat` from 4 to 2 elements.

My codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBbREV

```
<md-list>
    <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">md-list</md-subheader>

   <md-list-item>
        <p> title </p>
        <md-checkbox class="md-secondary"></md-checkbox>
    </md-list-item>

    <md-list-item>
        <p> title </p>
        <md-checkbox class="md-secondary"></md-checkbox>
    </md-list-item>
</mdlist>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it on the same row, Just align the layout like this,

```
<md-list-item layout="row">
```

Here is the updated [`Version`](http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/wBbRZv)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the checkboxes are not totally on the right of the screen, like the angular-material exemple shows

Answer (score 4):

There's actually been a change to the css that fixes what you are experiencing:

If you use the development version:

https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.min.css

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
</head>
```

Your page checkboxes should line up.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYdLam

Answer (score 0):

I think iam late to conversation but sharing my answer
use `<md-list-item layout="row">` and after your p element use `<span flex></span>`
**Make sure your md-list-item taking 100% width**